# MATH: Slowing projectile smoothly despite frame rate

Tags: c++, math

I have a ball that is travelling so:

```
ball.x += travelDirection.x * timeDelta * ballSpeed;
ball.y += travelDirection.y * timeDelta * ballSpeed;
```

Now, when the ball gets a certain distance, it starts to slow down, and I do that by using

```
BallSpeed *= 0.93458;
```

in the update function each frame until ballSpeed gets to less than 1, at which point we consider the ball to have stopped.

My problem is that if the framerate is faster than normal, this means it's going to slow down faster than I intend. I expect I need to use timeDelta in the above calculation, but I can't figure out exactly how. I expect it's some pretty simple math that I am missing. I have done a search, but can't find exactly what I am looking for.

If anyone can help, or point me to a solution, I would be grateful.

Comment: Instead of calculating the position incrementally, get a formula that calculates it for any time `t`. Then just derive `t` from the actual frame rate.

Comment: `ballspeed = ballspeed + (speed_change_per_ms * ms_since_last_update)`. In your case `speed_change_per_ms` would be a negative value. e.g.: `speed_change_per_ms = (ballspeed * (0.93458 - 1) / 1000.0)`

Answer (score 1):

To achieve smooth movement (including slowing down) you have to take framerate into account. It can be done by simply multiplying object's velocity by delta time.

In your case I would recommend something like this:

```
BallSpeed -= CHANGE_PER_SECOND * delta;
```

To read more about time step, go [here](http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/).

Comment: Link-only answers aren't very good. Please provide a summary or post it as a comment.

Comment: Copying article's content isn't either. I would post it as a comment but 50 reputation points are required.

Answer (score 0):

By multiplying ball speed by a constant each step, the values form a geometric sequence. The ball position is then the sum of a geometric sequence, also known as a geometric series. Both [Geometric Sequences and Series](http://www.regentsprep.org/regents/math/algtrig/atp2/geoseq.htm) have simple formulas to calculate arbitrary terms. They are:

Geometric Sequence: a_n = a_1 * r^(n-1)

Geometric Series: s_n = a_1 * (1 - r^n) / (1 - r)

Note that due to floating point rounding, calculating the values using these formulas may produce different results than calculating the values in increments each frame. I put together a test using both methods. It shows some slight differences in the last decimal place of the output. This could be significant depending on your application.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const float slowRate = 0.93458;
    const float dt = 1.0/60.0;
    const float ballSpeed = 100.0;
    float numSteps;
    float curBallSpeed = ballSpeed;
    float ballPosition;

    ballPosition = 0.0;
    for (float f = 0.0; f < 2.0; f += dt) {
        cout << ballPosition << " " << curBallSpeed << endl;
        ballPosition += curBallSpeed;
        curBallSpeed *= slowRate;
    }
    cout << endl;

    ballPosition = 0.0;
    // Since we are calculating directly, let's only do every second step
    for (float f = 0.0; f < 2.0; f += dt * 2) {
        numSteps = f / dt;
        ballPosition = ballSpeed * ((1.0 - pow(slowRate, numSteps)) / (1 - slowRate));
        curBallSpeed = ballSpeed * pow(slowRate, numSteps);
        cout << ballPosition << " " << curBallSpeed << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Note that updating the ball position by multiplying it's speed with a non-fixed time delta will produce a different result, since that doesn't account for the ball slowing down over that time delta.